# Is it possible to receive mail on the internet without an MTA?

Tags: debian, email

I just need to be able to receive email on my Debian server, not send it.

How can I do this with the lowest memory/CPU footprint? Do I still need a full MTA?

Answer (score 1):

You may use programs like [`fetchmail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetchmail) to transfer email from external mailboxes to local mailboxes.

- you can use fetchmail's `mda`  option to deliver messages to local mailboxes (mailbox file or maildir) **without** mta help. You can use e.g. [`procmail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) instead
- fetchmail supports `IDLE` command in IMAP protocol so it can retrieve messages in near real time.
  [AFAIK gmail servers offer/support `IDLE`]

Comment: Are there any options to receive mail on the server itself? i.e. root@domain.com goes into /var/mail/root - that's the kind of thing I'm looking for

Comment: @cantsay If you want to receive mail from someone else's MTA, you need an MTA.  You need to find the lightest weight one for your needs.  Reference: [Wikipedia: Message transfer agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)

Comment: **WHY** do you need small "footprint"?  **WHY** "standard MTA" footprint is too big? [ **I** do not know trivial solutions. Your determination may be insufficient for non simple solutions]